# Find all positive numbers divisible by 10 and less than n

Tags: python

I need to find all positive numbers that are divisible by 10 and less than n, i found a string with the same question but i have a hard time interpreting it as the user was using java so the codes are very different and confusing.

i tried to make a code by piecing together codes i've checked out but it only works if its divisible by other numbers, if its 10 it would keep going on forever with 0.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
x = 0
while x < n :    
    r = n % 10
    if r % 10 != 0 :
        x = x + r
print("positive numbers divisible by 10 ", x)
```

Comment: you need to increment x after each iteration

Comment: You can also just iterate in 10 interval `positive_numbers = [i for i in range(0, n, 10)]`

Answer (score 3):

Below is simpler code which will help to get the list of numbers divisible by 10 and less than n:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number n: "))
divisibleBy10 = []
for i in range(0, n):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        divisibleBy10.append(i)

print(divisibleBy10)
```

Comment: You can skip the if when you use a step size in the range

Comment: "... find all **positive** numbers that are divisible by 10 ...", your program outputs `0`

Comment: you have to enter n>10 to get an output

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
n = 100
i = 0
while i<n:
    if i%10==0:
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: "... find all **positive** numbers that are divisible by 10 ...", your program outputs `0`

Answer (score 1):

This code below tries to reduce the number of loops. If 'x' is extremely large, it helps to optimize the solution. The idea is to not do the divisibility check for each number starting from 1 to n-1. Here, we use the fact that the least positive number divisible by 10 is 10. The next number of interest is 10 + 10 =  20, there by skipping numbers 11 to 19. This helps improve the performance.

```
x = input('Enter any number ')
y = 10
while y < x:
    print(y)
    y = y + 10
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @borchvm Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following:

```
# grab the user's input
n = int(input('please enter a number: '))
# set x to 0, so the while loop can stop when 'n' is greater than '0'
x = 0
while n > x:
    if n % 10 == 0:
        print('{} is divisible by 10.'.format(n))
    n -= 1
```

So basically the loop enters with the value that the user inputs, let's say `10`.

- Is `10` greater than `0`? **Yes** (while loop executes), the `if` statement evaluates the remainder with the `mod`. The value **is** printed because the if statement evaluates **True** , the remainder is **equal** to zero. At last, n is subtracted by 1
- Is `9` greater than `0`? **Yes** (while loop executes), the `if` statement evaluates the remainder with the `mod`. The value **is not** printed because the if statement evaluates **False** , the remainder is **not equal** to zero. At last, n is subtracted by 1
- Is `8` greater than `0`? **Yes** (while loop executes), the `if` statement evaluates the remainder with the `mod`. The value **is not** printed because the if statement evaluates **False** , the remainder is **not equal** to zero. At last, n is subtracted by 1

...

And so on until **n** reaches `0`, the while loop stops because `0` is not greater than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think use inline for loop:

```
print([i for i in range(10,n,10) if i % 4 == 0])
```